# How do I share a bitmap and text - Android - Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-jetpack-compose, share

I am trying to send a bitmap of my composable along with some text. I am sending the bitmap to the app cache and then using the uri to send it in the share intent. I'm not sure where I am doing it wrong, so any help would be great.

Here is my share function:

```
fun shareImageToOthers(
            context: Context,
            text: String?,
            address: String,
            bitmap: Bitmap?,
        ): Intent
            val imageUri: Uri? = bitmap?.let { saveBitmapAndGetUri(context, it) }
            val chooserIntent2 = Intent.createChooser(Intent().apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, text)
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, address)
                putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
                flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            }, null)

            return chooserIntent2
```

This is how I save to bitmap and get the uri:

```
fun saveBitmapAndGetUri(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap): Uri {
            val path: String = context.externalCacheDir.toString() + "/filename.jpg"
            var out: OutputStream? = null
            val file = File(path)
            try {
                out = FileOutputStream(file)
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
                out.flush()
                out.close()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                context, "com.example.kbbqreview.util.provider", file
            )
        }
```

Also, I will add my manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.kbbqreview.util.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <!-- ressource file to create -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
```

And lastly, the file_paths.xml:

```
<external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
```

When I run this code, I can open the share sheet, but it doesn't load the bitmap. Most apps I try to send it to show an error message "File type not supported."

Comment: You should add the MIME type to the `Intent`, and consider using `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` instead of hand-assembling the `Intent`.

Comment: I've tried this, and still nothing comes up. I'll look around for more solutions and post it later. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I looked through it again. Your solution worked. The problem is many apps don't support bitmap sending with text I think. So I ended up just sharing a link to the image. Thank you for your answer!